# Android: addProximityAlert LocationManager Method doesn't send Broadcast

Tags: java, android, locationmanager, proximitysensor

I'm working on an Android Project where i'm using AddProximityAlert method, as you already know this method let you set a proximity alert for the location given by the position (latitude, longitude) and the given radius, and notify you if you are so close to it.

so i was working on that for three days ago and i was getting the same probleme again and again..

### in bref: this is my simple code.

### #MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.proximityalert;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager lm;

    //Defining Latitude & Longitude
    double lat=37.422006 ,long1=-122.084095;
    //Defining Radius
    float radius=1000;               

    //Intent Action 
    String ACTION_FILTER = "com.example.proximityalert";


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       //i'm registering my Receiver First
       registerReceiver(new ProximityReciever(), new IntentFilter(ACTION_FILTER));

       //i'm calling ther service Location Manager
       lm=(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

       //for debugging...
       lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);

       //Setting up My Broadcast Intent
       Intent i= new Intent(ACTION_FILTER);
       PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), -1, i, 0);

       //setting up proximituMethod
       lm.addProximityAlert(lat, long1, radius, -1, pi);

   }

@Override
//just For debugging to See the distance between my actual position and the aproximit point  
public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {

    Location old = new Location("OLD");
    old.setLatitude(lat);
    old.setLongitude(long1);

    double distance = newLocation.distanceTo(old);

    Log.i("MyTag", "Distance: " + distance);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}

}
```

---

### #ProximityReceiver.java

```
package com.example.proximityalert;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ProximityReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         // Key for determining whether user is leaving or entering 
         String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

         //Gives whether the user is entering or leaving in boolean form  
         boolean state = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

          if(state){
                // Call the Notification Service or anything else that you would like to do here
                Log.i("MyTag", "Welcome to my Area");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome to my Area", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }else{
              //Other custom Notification 
                Log.i("MyTag", "Thank you for visiting my Area,come back again !!");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Thank you for visiting my Area,come back again !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
     }
}
```

---

*#the probleme is when i run the program , the BroadcastReceiver(ProximityReciever) never never called by the system even if i'm veryyy close to the proximit point, and even if the debugger shows me that distance between the two locations is < 1000m :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured out somthing about this topic and why the addProximityAlert sames to be not working, I'm sharing this with you because I noticed that some people asked the same question before and they don't get any answer!

The answer was just in front of me but i didn't pay attention to it, so when i was reading the Android officiel documentation ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)) i saw this sentence "***Due to the approximate nature of position estimation, if the device passes through the given area briefly, it is possible that no Intent will be fired***"

what is that mean? it means when you are testing your app on the AVD and u send a gps coordinates(latitude, longitude) from the DDMS to AVD its really hard to 
 simulate the real aspect of a gps, (because in the first place u pick some point to be your proximPoint and just after that you choose anthor point very far from the proximPoint to see if its work) and thats not what it's happing with a real device.

so the solution is to test your app on a real device or with the DDMS try to change the coordiantes very slowly until you are in the zone wanted.